# IT says I can't put 2 300gb 10k drives in my system but 2 160gb 10k drives is ok? What could possibly cause that?

Tags: hard-drive

My stock system is a Dell Optiplex 760. Its got a core2 duo 8400 3.0 ghz. I have to do a lot of image processing which reads and writes 20-30 gb files to my hard drives. I requested two 300gb 10k western digital velociraptors. However my IT people have stated:

"The system can only handle a max 150GB on each drive at the speed he is requesting."

Does this make any sense? Under what circumstances could this be true?

Comment: budget, maybe?  doesn't strike me as a real excuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason IT said that is because the [spec sheet for the OptiPlex 760 [pdf]](http://www.dell.com/downloads/emea/products/optix/Optiplex_760_Spec_Sheet_en.pdf) listed the largest 10K drive at 160GB. I suspect it is because that was the largest 10K drive at available at the time.

I don't know of any reason they/you couldn't put in larger aftermarket drive.

Comment: I think this is the answer. I was just checking to make sure I wasn't missing something. The computers paid for with grant money anyway. I just want to be as efficient as possible when running $21K software for weeks on end.

Comment: oy... if that's really the answer i think kpierce8 needs new IT guys...

Answer (score 2):

The speed of hard drive isn't related to it's capacity in any way. Maybe they are just too expensive?

Comment: Actually there is a link, are areal density goes up, or the number of read/write heads increases, the aggregate bits/sec data rate under the heads will increase leading to faster performance.

Answer (score 1):

Even IF the onboard controller doesn't allow for 10k drives > 160 GB (which i doubt), that could be remedied with a modern addon PCI SATA II controller.

Comment: i know there's a controller-size-capability boundary somewhere around there but i think it's more like 128GB (or 137GB or something else well under 160...).  but you're right, it's unlikely.